# How to pass data between collection views Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i want to pass some data from a collection view to another collection view, but i got the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[IndexPath]?' to expected argument type 'Int'

When i'm pressing on a cell, i want to display some data to the other collection view.

This is the code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showItems", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ItemsViewController
        {


///Below is the error
            destination.items = guys[collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems]  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the `guys` array expects an `Int` index instead of an optional array of index paths.

One solution is to send the `indexPath` in the `sender` parameter

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showItems", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ItemsViewController
    {
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        destination.items = guys[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

`items` seems to be an array, but `didSelectItemAt` considers only the current index path. So either declare one `item` or create an array

```
destination.items = [guys[indexPath.row]]
```

The other solution is to use indeed `indexPathsForSelectedItems` but you have to unwrap the optional somehow and map the index paths to the rows and get the items at the given indices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try code below ?

```
if let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.row {
    destination.items = guys[index]
}
```